# Google File Uploader with two returns to html

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm making a file uploader which would upload to Google Drive, however, in the script code when it is wanted to once uploaded the file to redirect to a thank you page it stays in the same page of the form. Here's the code:

**Code.gs**

```
function doGet(e) {

return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form.html');

}

function uploadFiles(form) {

try {

var dropbox = "foldername";
var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropbox);

if (folders.hasNext()) {
  folder = folders.next();
} else {
  folder = DriveApp.createFolder(dropbox);
}

var blob = form.myFile;    
var file = folder.createFile(blob);    
file.setDescription("Uploaded by " + form.myName);

return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('success.html');

} catch (error) {

return error.toString();
  }
  }
```

**form.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<style type="text/css">
body {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
</style>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<div align="center">
<p><img src="sampleimage.jpg"></p>
<table width="459" border="0">
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td width="462"><div align="center">
      <hr>
    </div>
      <form id="myForm" align="center">
        <input type="text" name="myName" placeholder="Your name..">
        <input type="file" name="myFile">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload File" 
       onclick="this.value='Uploading..';
                google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fileUploaded)
                .uploadFiles(this.parentNode);
                return false;">
      </form>
      <div id="output"></div>
      <script>
function fileUploaded(status) {
    document.getElementById('myForm').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = status;
}
      </script>
    <style>
 input { display:block; margin: 20px; }

      </style>
    <hr></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<h3>&nbsp;</h3>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

**success.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<style type="text/css">
body {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
</style>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<div align="center">
<p><img src="sampleimage2.jpg"></p>
<table width="459" border="0">
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td width="462"><div align="center">
      <hr>
    </div>
    <p>File Uploaded! Click here: <a   href="https://www.google.com.ec">Return</a></p>
      <div id="output"></div>
    <style>
 input { display:block; margin: 20px; }

      </style>
    <hr></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<h3>&nbsp;</h3>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try combining the two HTML files into one. The flow would go something like

1. Server launches form.html
2. Client-side function shows the first div, containing the upload.
3. Your on-click flow would stay the same
4. When the client gets to `fileUploaded()` as the success handler, you hide the form div (as you've already done) *then show the success div*.

This way, you're going back and forth between one client and one server instead of trying to manage multiple client instances.